# database update query that updates all 1's with 0 and all 0's with 1

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have below details :-

### Table name : test

### column name : data_reset

### Data row wise : 0,1,1,0,1,0,0

Need to write query that update all 1's with 0 and all 0's with 1.
Also provide the same using hibernate JPA, if we can do that.

Answer (score 0):

If column values are always 0 or 1, we can use *Bitwise Exclusive OR operator*.

```
UPDATE test SET data_reset = (data_reset ^ 1);
```

**JPA Query**

```
Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE Test SET dataReset = (dataReset ^ 1)");
 int updateCount = em.executeUpdate();
```

A TransactionRequiredException is thrown if no transaction is active.

On success - the executeUpdate method returns the number of objects that have been modified by the query.
Here em is  EntityManager Object.
For more ref visit [UPDATE SET Queries in JPA/JPQL](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/update)